# Pretty much same SQL commands, but different injection Payloads! WHY?

Tags: sql, sql-injection, owasp

OWASP Juice Shop:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = '' AND password = '' AND deletedAt IS NULL
```

Payload:

> ' OR 1=1;--

OWASP Mutillidae II:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='' AND password=''
```

Payload:

> ' OR 1=1 --

I really don't understand. There is not much of a difference in commands, but Juice Shop payload won't work in Mutillidae. It works Vice Versa.

Furthermore in Mutillidae, we have to enter payload in both username and password fields (same payload), however in JuiceShop entering random thing in Password would work.

Someone please explain WHY?

Please I really need to understand this concept before moving on.

Comment: Why noone learning sql injection ever leans *SQL?* I really don't get it. It's like learning how to steal a car but never learning how to drive one. Why not to add the payload to the query and just examine the result?

Comment: Umm that was pretty much the first thing I did.
And I know SQL pretty much. Had some Hands on with it but then switched to MONGO DB

Comment: I can make sense of errors too, but this one is beyond my scope rn.
Should I share the error message?

Comment: It is possible that you need a space at the end. I've read that some database comments require a whitespace after the comment indicators, whereas some others don't e.g., `'OR 1=1;--` may not work on all, but `'OR 1=1;-- ` should work. I'd usually put a whitespace before the -- as well, but probably isn't necessary.

Comment: @seanb Man that really worked. So "Some" versions require a space, if I would put a space after "--" in normal versions, would that affect query.

Comment: @seanb Please post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this as a comment but was the answer - so posting below

> It is possible that you need a space at the end. I've read that some database comments require a whitespace after the comment indicators, whereas some others don't e.g., `' OR 1=1;--` may not work on all, but `' OR 1=1;--`  should work. I'd usually put a whitespace before the -- as well, but probably isn't necessary.